# change tty login timeout - ArchLinux

Tags: linux, login, tty, timeout, getty

By default when I login to my Arch linux box in a tty, there is a timeout after I type my username but before I type my password.

So it goes like this

```
Login:  mylogin <enter>
Password:
(+ 60 seconds)
Login:
```

As you can see, if I don't type the password it recycles the prompt -- I want it to wait indefinitely for my password instead of recycling the login prompt.

Is this possible?

It seems like the `--timeout` option to `agetty` would be what I want. However, I tried adding this flag in the getty files in `/usr/lib/systemd/system/` (the option is not used by default), and rebooting -- it seemed to have no effect.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`agetty` calls `login` after reading in the user name, so any timeout when reading the password is done by `login`.

To change this, edit `/etc/login.defs` and change the LOGIN_TIMEOUT value.

```
#
# Max time in seconds for login
#
LOGIN_TIMEOUT       60
```

Comment: How would you get it to last infinitely?

Comment: @AnEpicPerson It's not documented, as far as I can see, but looking through the code there is `#define ALARM 60` and `timeout = getdef_unum ("LOGIN_TIMEOUT", ALARM); if (timeout > 0) { (void) alarm (timeout); }`. So putting `LOGIN_TIMEOUT 0` in login.defs ought to disable any timeout.

Answer (score 1):

1. In Arch, programs install defaults to `/usr/lib`. You should not be manually messing around in there (almost ever); definitely not with `systemd`. `systemd` provides overriding of default units for a reason (see the ["Unit Load Path" section](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html)).
2. Part of this is a security issue. The timeout checks back for negligence (e.g., you type your whole password, but forget to press enter and are distracted by something). You should be aware that disabling it is not the most secure decision here.
3. When you edit or override a unit, you need to run `systemctl daemon-reload` in order for systemd to fully recognize the change. After creating the new unit in `/etc/systemd/`, you must `daemon-reload` and then `disable` the default unit and `enable` your new unit. Then, rebooting should yield the results you want. (*Note*: I advise against doing so though; see point 2.)

Comment: Regarding your point 2. -- the practical import of doing this is so my 4-year old can manage to type in her 9-letter password before being thwarted.  Re your answer in its entirety, please find it in your heart to give me a *solution* to my question.

Comment: I had thought you were actually on the right track with the `--timeout` option, but looking further into it (namely, `agetty`'s man page), it seems the `--timeout` option refers to the entering of the username, not the password.

Comment: @HalosGhost No need to put '$' before commands when editing posts, it is wasteful, and that makes the more difficult to cut and paste. Only do when commands and output are intermixed in one block

Comment: @Zelda, I'm not actually sure why you posted that here. But, I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: -1, this post answers many things, except for what the OP asked for.